# raspberry pi cluster taking forever to run mpirun

Tags: cluster

Hi so I have been following the guide: Raspberry Pi Supercomputing and Scientific Programming and in Chapter 6 I need to run the following command:

mpirun -hostfile myhostfile -np 4 hostname

where myhostfile is a file that contains the IP addresses of my raspberry pis. At this step I have installed all the appropriate libraries and connected my raspberry pis to a wifi router

However when i try running this command it takes forever to execute

Some details about the system I am using:

So I am using 4 Raspberry pi 3 B+ models and all of them are connected using a cabled LAN. I have been running this command for roughly 1.5 hours and there has not been any output. I know the processor is still running given it keeps blinking _ . Also heres a link to the guide: link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-2878-4

Comment: you really need to add more detail. Where can we find the guide, what model Pi, OS. Personally I would use cabled LAN as it's more reliable and stable. And what does 'takes forever' mean? Does it actually do something? Is there any output, processor activity, etc etc etc. Please update your question with relevant details

Comment: @Dirk thanks for the response! So I am using 4 Raspberry pi 3 B+ models and all of them are connected using a cabled LAN. I have been running this command for roughly 1.5 hours and there has not been any output. I know the processor is still running given it keeps blinking _ . Also heres a link to the guide: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-2878-4

Comment: Pls add these details to your question, as requested.

Comment: @Dirk added the details as requested! hope it is sufficient